# "OK" button is disabled in "Create new android virtual device"

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I am trying to create a new Android Virtual Device using eclipse(**Window** > **AVD Manager**). But I'm not able to do so since **OK** button is disabled even though I have selected **CPU/ABI** option in the GUI properly. Also, there is no space in **AVD Name**.

Can someone please help me figure out why OK button is disabled here?

I can't post snapshot here, since I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Sounds like you probably have it set to an unsupported configuration - perhaps a CPU/ABI option requiring image files that you have not downloaded or something like that.

Comment: Are you using eclipse or android studio?

Comment: Problem was resolved after restarting eclipse. Thanks

Comment: Can you post a screenshot to somewhere like imgur.com and give a link to it?

Comment: @PhilRingsmuth That was a good idea.

Comment: I had selected both Emulation Options [Snapshop and Use Host GPU], that's why OK button was disabled.